# MySQL UTF-8 issue with c caron (hatscheck) from Czech language

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

This problems origins from TYPO3, where I can't insert a c caron (č) in RTE while s caron (š) works. But soon I realised, that the problem also occurs, when I directly insert a c caron in phpMyAdmin.

Charset in DB and the table is both `UTF8_unicode_ci`, I also tried `UTF8mb4_unicode_ci` with no success.

Error: `Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x8D \x0D\x0A' for column 'bodytext' at row 1`

Thanks in advance!

PS: Similar problem with Ś `Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9A' for column 'bodytext' at row 1`

Comment: You may also need to correctly set your connection string to use utf8. Maybe something here will help : http://superuser.com/questions/741864/how-to-display-text-in-utf8-from-mysql-phpmyadmin AND https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: utf8 and utf8mb4 handle Czech characters the same.  0D0A is CRLF.  Hex C48D is the encoding for `č` in utf8 (and utf8mb4).  Ditto for C59A and `Ś`.  The puzzling thing is that #1366 usually occurs when a non-utf8 encoding is fed to a utf8 column.  You have the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments! I've found the error: Databse was UTF-8, table was UTF-8 but the field was Latin-1... LOL! Changed to UTF-8 and now it works. Thanks for all your help!